# PHP Script to force download text file

Tags: php, text, download, mime

I have a Text file created by php script using str_pad() with spaces, I want to download the same without losing those spaces. When I download using ftp, there is no issue, all the spaces in the text files are intact. 
But when I use this download script so that the user can download, it gives junk characters instead of spaces and data is scrambled. Pl help if there is any other way of downloading this file by the user.

My php file to download - download.php:

```
<?php
function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{

if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 $known_mime_types=array(
"txt" => "text/plain",
"html" => "text/html",
"php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
 if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
    $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
 } else {
    $mime_type="application/force-download";
 };
 };

 @ob_end_clean();


 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
$range=intval($range);
if(!$range_end) {
    $range_end=$size-1;
} else {
    $range_end=intval($range_end);
}

$new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header("Content-Length: $new_length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
$new_length=$size;
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); 
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
fseek($file, $range);

while(!feof($file) &&
    (!connection_aborted()) &&
    ($bytes_send<$new_length)
      )
{
    $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
    print($buffer); //echo($buffer);
    flush();
    $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
}
 fclose($file);
 } else
 die('Error - can not open file.');

die();
}

set_time_limit(0);


$file_path=$_REQUEST['filename'];

output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');

?>
```

HTML file which calls the download.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Downloading Text file</title>
</head><body>
<br>
<br>
<a href='download.php?filename=Text1.txt'>Download print file </a><br>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

My original Text1.txt file output which is created by a php script using str_pad():

```
       3M India Ltd                                                   78788
       No.2, Abbayappa Layout, 4th Main, NS Palaya,                               
       Bannerghatta Road, Bangalore 560 076                           11/05/2012
                                                                        10:10:57

              500                          322
                                           AAACB5984DXM001            29400127541
                                           KA-01-N-2345               29400127541
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and see what happens. for the line

> if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))

change to

> if (fopen($file, 'r'))

Comment: There is no difference after making the above changes given by you, is there any other solution.

Comment: Sorry, this is the output of the text file : <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in <b>/home/public_html/svga/datagrid/examples/download.php</b> on line <b>90</b><
<b>Warning</b>:  feof(): supp

Comment: try debug with `echo file_get_contents($file); exit;`,  put this code at the beginning of your function and check the results, if no problem then continue down the function.